# ADB NoteBook shows Successfully executed even though "Status_Msg": "Failure"

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have an issue, when I execute ADB notebook which calls multiple notebooks, pipeline shows successful but when I go through the status output it shows "Status_Msg": "Failure",
and few notbooks are failed.
Do I need to comment any thing in that code only if the notebook success message should be taken by output of the pipeline and same for status_msg is failure the pipeline should be failed.
Please go through the image and help me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJo56.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the status message is a failure then pipeline should be a failure. But here, Some custom Exceptions and runtime errors might not hurt the Notebook activity. Please consider the status message and work on your code. 
If you want a pipeline to fail when the status message is a failure, then try to `raise/throw` error exception to stop your Notebook activity. Try to use a `try .. exception..assert False` statement block to handle your custom exceptions.

Please go through the below links to learn more about it.

https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D53f00001WE495CAD/is-there-a-way-to-capture-the-notebook-logs-from-adf-pipeline

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/13515